# Changed from sendmail to sengdrid, now mails end at spam

Tags: php, email, sendmail, sendgrid

I'been sending emails through sendmail for a long time, I want to change to sendgrid, but my mails end up in the spam folder.

I been using sendmail so I suppose my domain already has some reputation, I don't know what else could be affecting my setup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check that your SPF records correctly include Sendgrid as a valid sender, for starters.

Comment: Setted the SPF record but it keep sending my mails to spam :(

Comment: Did you *just* set the SPF record? It can take a while for email providers to pick up on the new one - they cache it.

Comment: Yeah, gonna wait 24 hours and try again